# Get maxInactiveInterval value in JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, el

I am trying to refresh a page when session has timedout. I am adding this into my `<head>` section of HTML:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh"
      content="${sessionScope['maxInactiveInterval']};url=${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/index.htm?reason=expired"/>
```

However this: `${sessionScope['maxInactiveInterval']}` or `${sessionScope.maxInactiveInterval}` prints out empty value (nothing).

I know that in JSF I can use: `#{session.maxInactiveInterval}` and it works. How to make this for in JSP page?

Comment: have you tried using `sessionScope.maxInactiveInterval`?

Comment: Yes I had. I have mentioned this in my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

below line will give you `maxInactiveInterval`

```
${pageContext.session.maxInactiveInterval}
```

Because `sessionScope` maps only session-scoped variable names to their values,
Where as `pageContext.session` gives session object for the client

You can find this in [Official Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html).

Comment: Kinda lost the pageContext object from mind. Upvote as it reminded me the fact you mentioned :)